# Do I have to check "Enable Bookmark Sync" on both machines running 11.04?

Tags: sync

If I want to sync firefox bookmarks only one direction, do I have to check "enable bookmark sync" on both machines? Both are running 11.04 and firefox 6.01.
How about both directions?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't enable bookmark sync on a machine, then it will only use the local bookmark store.

So if you want to share bookmarks between two systems, both must enable bookmark synchronisation.  Unfortunately, I don't think any of the Firefox bookmark synchronisation systems support one-way synchronisation, so this will give you two way sync.